# SQL for retrieving a result set of two date ranges

Tags: sql

I need a SQL statement that will return a result set containing the person IDs who have a status code of 'DE' between one time frame, and a status code of 'PE' between another time frame.
Example tables

```
id | name 
--- ------
1    Joe  
2    Jane 

status | start_date | end_date  | person_id
------- ------------ ----------- -----------
   DE    2016-12-01  2016-12-28   1
   PE    2017-02-01  2017-02-28   1
   DE    2016-12-01  2016-12-28   2
```

if the 'DE' timeframe was between 2016-12-01 and 2016-12-28 and the 'PE' timeframe was between 2017-02-01 and 2017-02-28 I would expect Joe to be returned in the the query set.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet with problems like this is to break them down into seperate SQL, so go at this table twice. Once for the `DE` and once again for the `PE`:

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE status = 'DE' and start_date = '2016-12-01' AND end_date = '2016-12-28';

SELECT name FROM table WHERE status = 'PE' and start_date = '2017-02-01' AND end_date = '2017-02-28';
```

Now you've got to result sets that you can test against each other:

```
SELECT name 
FROM
    (SELECT name FROM table WHERE status = 'DE' and start_date = '2016-12-01' AND end_date = '2016-12-28') t1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT name FROM table WHERE status = 'DE' and start_date = '2016-12-01' AND end_date = '2016-12-28') t2 ON t1.name = t2.name;
```

Since you aren't actually selecting from the second derived table, you could go at this with a correlated subquery as well, using the same logic:

```
SELECT name
FROM table t1 
WHERE
    status = 'DE' and 
    start_date = '2016-12-01' AND 
    end_date = '2016-12-28' AND
    name IN (SELECT name FROM table t2 WHERE t1.name = t2.name status = 'PE' and start_date = '2017-02-01' AND end_date = '2017-02-28');
```

Which may perform better.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand what you need.

but,

```
SELECT * FROM table1 where (select count(*) from table2 where table1.id = table2.person_id and (([status] = 'DE' and start_data between '2016-12-01' and '2016-12-28') or ([status] = 'PE' and start_data between '2017-02-01' and '2017-02-28')) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which sql you're using but this query should work fine with PostgreSQL

```
select Res.name from   (
                select * from table1 inner join table2 on Table1.id = Table2.person_id
                where (status = 'DE' and start_date >= '2016-12-01' and end_date <= '2016-12-28') 
                or
                (status = 'PE' and start_date >= '2017-02-01' and end_date <= '2017-02-28')
                    ) as Res
    group by Res.name having count(*) > 1
```

Or you can use this statement as well

```
select table1.name from  table1 
inner join table2 t1 on table1.id = t1.person_id
where status = 'DE' and start_date >= '2016-12-01' and end_date <= '2016-12-28' 
and 
exists ( select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.person_id = t1.person_id and 
status = 'PE' and start_date >= '2017-02-01' and end_date <= '2017-02-28' )
```